# RxJava/Android Observable not reacting to state changes

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

When I call onNext for a Subject, the observable does not pick up any changes and does not react appropriately.

So our product uses a canBus to send data from our controller to our hardware and we are using rxJava to handle data changes. Already we have rxJava working with the UI perfectly but for our new Alexa feature, for some reason when I call the model functions directly to change values (and in turn call subject.onNext), nothing happens. I can't seem to find the error. Flow is below:

Alexa response:

```
case "ShowerState":
            //TODO figure out shower state alexa case
            Log.d(TAG, "Intent: ShowerIntent");
            if(action.equals("on")){
                Log.d(TAG, "Action: On");
                digitalShowerModel.changeShowerStateValue(DigitalShowerModel.DigitalShowerState.ON);
            }else if(action.equals("off")){
                Log.d(TAG, "Action: Off");
                digitalShowerModel.changeShowerStateValue(DigitalShowerModel.DigitalShowerState.OFF);
            }
            break;
```

Digital Shower model:

```
public void changeShowerStateValue(DigitalShowerState digitalShowerState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Change shower state value");
    currentShowerState = digitalShowerState;
    currentShowerStateSubject.onNext(currentShowerState);
}
```

The observer flow:

```
private void initDigitalShowerCanMsgs() {
    Observable.combineLatest(
            digitalShowerRepository.getShowerStateChanges(),
            digitalShowerRepository.getWaterTempChanges(),
            digitalShowerRepository.getWaterOutputChanges(),
            digitalShowerRepository.getWaterFlowChanges(),
            Observable.interval(TIME_BETWEEN_DIGITAL_SHOWER_MSGS, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
            new Function5<DigitalShowerModel.DigitalShowerState,
                                    Integer, DigitalShowerModel.WaterOutput,
                                    DigitalShowerModel.WaterFlow, Long, ArrayList<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public ArrayList<Integer> apply(DigitalShowerModel.DigitalShowerState digitalShowerState, Integer temp, DigitalShowerModel.WaterOutput waterOutput, DigitalShowerModel.WaterFlow waterFlow, Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    ArrayList<Integer> dataBytes = new ArrayList<>();
                    dataBytes.add(digitalShowerState.ordinal());
                    dataBytes.add(temp);
                    dataBytes.add(waterOutput.ordinal());
                    dataBytes.add(waterFlow.ordinal());
                    return dataBytes;
                }
            })
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Observer<ArrayList<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ArrayList<Integer> dataBytes) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "SHOWER CAN MESSAGE OBSERVER");
                    FC_Cmd[FlexDefs.CTLESVSTATE].fflxout.execute(dataBytes.get(0), dataBytes.get(1),
                            dataBytes.get(2), dataBytes.get(3), 0, 0);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

Digital Shower Repository:

```
public Observable<DigitalShowerModel.DigitalShowerState> getShowerStateChanges() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Get shower state changes DigitalShowerRepository");
    return digitalShowerModel.getCurrentShowerStateSubject();
}
```

Digital Shower Model(Observer):

```
    public Subject<DigitalShowerState> getCurrentShowerStateSubject() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Get shower state value");
    return currentShowerStateSubject;
}
```

I don't understand why changes aren't being processed. The log message "change shower state value" is being hit. Also the observer is observing as it is hitting the "Shower can observer log". I also thought it could be this observer that also calls getShowerStateChanges affecting it somehow:

Digital shower screen fragment:

```
 Observable.combineLatest(
        digitalShowerRepository.getShowerStateChanges(),
        digitalShowerRepository.getWaterOutputChanges(), new BiFunction<DigitalShowerModel.DigitalShowerState, DigitalShowerModel.WaterOutput, Pair>() {
            @Override
            public Pair<DigitalShowerModel.DigitalShowerState, DigitalShowerModel.WaterOutput>
                    apply(DigitalShowerModel.DigitalShowerState digitalShowerState, DigitalShowerModel.WaterOutput waterOutput) throws Exception {
                return new Pair<>(digitalShowerState, waterOutput);
            }
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<Pair>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                digitalShowerDisposables.add(d);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Pair pair) {
                if(!wasInitiatedByUser) {
                    rainHeadRdoBtn.setOnTouchListener(null);
                    showerHeadRdoBtn.setOnTouchListener(null);
                    wandRdoBtn.setOnTouchListener(null);
                    showerOptions.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

                    if (pair.first == DigitalShowerModel.DigitalShowerState.ON) {
                        switch ((DigitalShowerModel.WaterOutput) pair.second) {
                            case RAINHEAD:
                                rainHeadRdoBtn.setChecked(true);
                                break;
                            case SHOWERHEAD:
                                showerHeadRdoBtn.setChecked(true);
                                break;
                            case WAND:
                                wandRdoBtn.setChecked(true);
                                break;
                        }
                    } else if (pair.first == DigitalShowerModel.DigitalShowerState.OFF) {
                        showerOptions.clearCheck();
                    }

                    rainHeadRdoBtn.setOnTouchListener(DigitalShowerScreenFragment.this);
                    showerHeadRdoBtn.setOnTouchListener(DigitalShowerScreenFragment.this);
                    wandRdoBtn.setOnTouchListener(DigitalShowerScreenFragment.this);
                    showerOptions.setOnCheckedChangeListener(DigitalShowerScreenFragment.this);
                }
                wasInitiatedByUser = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
    });
```

But this seems to be a primarily UI change observer. Big note: I did not write the observer, however I do understand what is happening minus this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have forgot to add this to the alexa response class and it worked after I added:

```
TouchSteamApplication.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
```